# How to get internet speed an android device actually downloading and uploading data?

Tags: android

Actually, I am doing a college project and I have an idea about developing
 an android app which shows internet speed on the device. I want to know the 
actual internet speed device using and also want to show the total data consumed
by an application in a day. I have searched a lot on internet but still
unsatisfied with answers. I did some research but still not have an idea how
to do it. I have created design for the application. Everything in the project 
is created.

To be more precise, I don't want to know maximum speed of wifi or internet.
I want to display the current internet speed of the device. 
I tried to use ConnectionManager and activeConnectionInfo but still with empty hands.

I am in my engineering and I have to complete this project in a month. Please help me with some basic code that I need to include.

Comment: "I have searched a lot on internet but still unsatisfied with answers" -- we cannot help you with those answers unless you link to them. "I want to display the current internet speed of the device" -- what is your definition of "internet speed of the device"?

Comment: if something is downloading in the background by other application then my app should be able to display the download speed.. If no app is using the internet then it should simply show 0.

Comment: Hopefully, you cannot spy on downloads being done by other applications. Beyond that: what happens if more than one app is downloading?

Comment: I don't want to know what other applications are downloading. I just want  to know the internet speed of the device. I tried to use getLinkSpeed but still don't know the exact steps to use any code. There are some apps in apple store as well as play store that shows the internet speed of the device. My main idea is the same to show overall upload and download speed android device is transferring the data.

Comment: "I just want to know the internet speed of the device" -- but you are defining that in terms of what other apps are downloading. You are welcome to attempt to use `TrafficStats` for this, but I don't know how frequently that gets updated and whether it is sufficiently real time for your purposes.